# Random coin toss; toss 10 coins; repeat 100 times

Tags: simulation

I want to simulate a coin toss game in which 10 coins are tossed. Afterwards, I want to repeat this simulation 100 times. So far I have:

```
Coin10 = {}
For[i = 0, i < 10, i++, AppendTo[Coin10, RandomInteger[]]]
Total[Coin10]
```

How can I run this simulation 100 times?

Comment: `RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {100, 10}]` or `RandomChoice[{"H", "T"}, {100, 10}]`. For the sum: `Total@RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {100, 10}]`.

Comment: You know how to repeat a coin toss 10 times, but not how to repeat the whole thing 100 times?

Answer (score 9):

The OP's requirements are so simple as to produce an uninteresting problem. I thought I'd try to make it interesting by generalizing it to a simulation with any specified number of coins in a given toss and any specified number of tosses in given simulation run. But that was still uninteresting, so I did it in a way I'd been thinking about but hadn't got around to doing before: Have a simulation run return an association which would allow queries on both parameters and results ex-post-facto.

Here is what I came up with.

```
simulate[coins_, tosses_] :=
  Module[{sim, hds, events = coins tosses},
    sim = <||>;
    AppendTo[sim, "coins" -> coins];
    AppendTo[sim, "tosses" -> tosses];
    AppendTo[sim, "raw" -> RandomInteger[1, {tosses, coins}]];
    AppendTo[sim, "heads" -> Total[sim["raw"], {2}]];
    AppendTo[sim, "tails" -> coins - sim["heads"]];
    hds = Total[sim["heads"]];
    AppendTo[
      sim,
      "outcome" -> <|"heads" -> hds, "tails" -> events - hds|>];
    AppendTo[sim, "%heads" -> 100. hds/events];
    AppendTo[sim, "%tails" -> 100. (1. - hds/events)];
    sim]
```

Very pedestrian code, I admit, but sometimes that's what works best.

Let's see how it works. First a simple simulation, 5 coins tossed 4 times.

```
SeedRandom[2]; simulate[5, 4]
```

> ```
>  <|"coins" -> 5, "tosses" -> 4, 
>    "raw" -> 
>       {{1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1}}, 
>    "heads" -> {4, 2, 2, 3}, "tails" -> {1, 3, 3, 2}, 
>    "outcome" -> <|"heads" -> 11, "tails" -> 9|>, 
>    "%heads" -> 55., "%tails" -> 45.|>
> ```

Since the raw outcome is included, any query not built-in can be made on the raw data.

Now let's look the orginal problem, only upping the ante to 500 tosses of 10 fair coins.

```
SeedRandom[1]; run = simulate[10, 500];
run["outcome"]
```

> `<|"heads" -> 2460, "tails" -> 2540|>`

```
Row[{"Percentages  heads: ", run["%heads"], "  tails: ", run["%tails"]}]
```

> `Percentages  heads: 49.2  tails: 50.8`